# Problem to test and mock uuid with angular and jasmine

Tags: angular, mocking, jasmine, uuid, stub

I cannot figure out to mock uuid4 within my test.

I have a object to test, which looks something like that:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

...

{
    id: uuidv4(),
    testnumer: 'S1EQ20024808SSUS1',
    productid: 'S1P10186044S005',
    starttime: new Date(Date.now()),
  };
```

with jest it seems to be easy with

```
jest.mock('uuid', () => ({ v4: () => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' }));
```

but I cant figure it out to write a test within the objewct is created with angular and jasmine.

The date is easy with:

```
jasmine.clock().mockDate();
```

I tried simon.

```
sinon.stub(uuid, 'v4').returns('cd589508-dcd6-44d8-99f8-ea99a54c15ed');
```

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

The way to make this work is to wrap `uuid` in a service that you can then easily mock in your tests:

**uuid.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UuidService {
  v4(): string {
    return v4();
  }
}
```

In your testfile:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let uuidServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<UuidService>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    uuidServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('UuidService', ['v4']);
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SomeComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: UuidService, useValue: uuidServiceMock }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  ...

  it('is a test using uuid', () => {
    const newUuid = 'some-randomly-generated-uuid';
    uuidServiceMock.v4.and.returnValue(newUuid);

    component.methodUsingUuid();

    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try doing this in your `spec` file.

```
import * as uuidWrapper from 'uuid';

...
spyOn(uuidWrapper, 'v4').and.returnValue(/* your mock value goes here */);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
but I get:
`
Error: <spyOn> : v4 is not declared writable or has no setter
`

Comment: This does not work anymore, as newer environments have module isolation preventing anything from the outside from tampering with modules (which honestly does make sens)